# Search form integration on here map using JS API

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm trying to show a search form in my Here map so the user can search for a place (and based on the user selection the web would create a new marker in the map). Is it possible with the Here Maps Javascript API? I couldn't find any example...

Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to layer another div on top of your map and follow this example?
https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoding_suggestions

Comment: Thanks for the link! I came up with the same solution but with shittier code (I’m a backend guy xD). Still it would be really great to have it fully integrated into the map.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: @Antamack in the example from Drosera it is implemented wit the HERE maps javascript API.

Comment: What I’m looking for is an embedded search form into the map. Like when you are using the map from the here maps website. The link provides a solution that works but is not embedded, it’s just tied to the map. I’m wondering if there’s something more “cohesive”.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer ready to use code snippets for this user case. this can be checked in the example section of our api documentation. https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoding_suggestions